# What did emergency medical hologram mean when he referenced Epocrates in S1E2 Parallax?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

When the emergency medical hologram (EMH) said, "Now I know how Epocrates felt when the king needed him to trim a hangnail?" What did he mean? Is there a story behind this? When I look Epocrates up in Google it shows me Viagra ads. :(

**Correction**:  Hippocrates not Epocrates. The actual quote is, "Now I know how Hippocrates felt when the king needed him to trim a hangnail?"

Comment: Related Meta discussion: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3581/1027

Comment: The latter edit would be better off on a blog - ask Jack.B.Nimble if he wants to host that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It was [Hippocrates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippocrates), one of the most famous physicians ever and widely considered "father of medicine" (as in [Hippocratic oath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippocratic_Oath))

The hangnail remark from EMH meant that he was an advanced super-doctor and got asked to do something completely beneath his skillset (specifically, he was asked for soil samples in that episode).

Hippocrates was mentioned [a couple of times in Star Trek canon](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Hippocrates).

The phrase served as both a comedic quip, AND a character building device, reinforcing The Doctor's tendency towards snobbishness and his total lack of self-esteem issues.

Comment: OK. That makes more sense. How come I heard "Epocrates"? If a EMH were real I could get my ears checked.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts There's a natural tendency when speaking the english language to pause just before pronouncing a soft "h" sound...it has a name, but I can't remember what it is.  That's probably why you heard it as "ep" rather than "hip"

Comment: In the final scene of ST:VOY 3x18 "Darkling", he actually recites (something akin to) the [Hippocratic Oath](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippocratic_Oath): "I swear this oath by Apollo [the] physician, by Aesculapius, by Health, and by all the Gods and Goddesses: in whatsoever place that I enter, I will enter to help the sick and heal the injured. [And I will do no harm.](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Primum_non_nocere)"